# Automated User Registration with Salesforce IDP

Tags: user, single-sign-on, user-registration, identity-provider

I was wondering if you can automate the signup process in case Salesforce is IDP.

For example I have two applications A and B (service provider) and I want to add Salesforce as IDP.

Is it possible to make application users A and B automatically sign up for IDP so that they can use SSO?

Or what are the various alternatives to solve this problem?

Comment: You can call an API to create their user account and other related records as necessary. Here's an example: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/267464/composite-api-create-person-account-and-community-user-in-a-single-call

Comment: thanks for your comment.. but call from what? the application A? or another system?..because if i'm not access to application A how i can?

Comment: Call from a system where the user's information is available. If there's a user sign-up page (hosted on whatever system, Salesforce could be that too), then call from there.

Comment: i have configure SSO in my Salesforce IDP.. but in a login page can i add a Registration button?..because with SSO user from application A is redirect to login page of Salesforce IDP. But then he can only login not register..sorry if i'm not clear the problem

Comment: Yes, you can ask them to self-register on Salesforce login page: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/identity_external/identity_external_registration

Comment: Thanks,, Another solution (maybe) is create a chain... App A -> SF IDP -> Google Auth... and user can register in IDP from Google and user email as federation id